# What is wrong with my code highlighting the column and row?

Tags: html, css

I want my table to look like the one in this example https://codepen.io/davesantos/pen/etHgh. However, when I could not reproduce the code on my site to look like that. it seems like the hover effect happened in the layer behind the table.

This is how it turned out on my page: https://www.avmbiotech.com/our-focus/immune-reset-for-autoimmune-diseases/

Here is my code:

````
<html>
<head>
<style>
* { box-sizing:border-box;}
table {overflow: hidden; display:inline-block;}
td:hover::before { background: #233477; content: ' '; height: 100%; left: -5000px; position: absolute; top: 0; width: 10000px; z-index: -2;}
td:hover::after { background: #a63f44; content: ' '; height: 10000px; left: 0; position: absolute; top: -5000px; width: 100%; z-index:-1;}
td, th {border: 1px; padding: 10px; position: relative;}
th { background-color:white;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
      <th style="background-color:#FFF"></th>
      <th style="background-color:#233477">HALT-MS Nash 2015 <b>BEAM</b></th>
      <th style="background-color:#233477">Crohns Haselblatt 2012 Brierley 2018 Cy-ATG</th>
      <th style="background-color:#233477">T1D Malmegrim 2017 Cy-ATG</th>
      <th style="background-color:#233477">AVM0703</th>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <th style="background-color:#233477">CD4 Nadir*</th>
    <td>22 cells per μL</td>
    <td>115 cell per μL</td>
    <td>155 cells per μL</td>
    <td><b>25 cells per μL</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th style="background-color:#233477">CD8 Nadir</th>
    <td>50 cells per μL</td>
    <td>172 cells per μL</td>
    <td>464 cells per μL</td>
    <td><b>1.4 cells per μL</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th style="background-color:#233477">B Lymphs Nadir</th>
    <td>12 cells per μL</td>
    <td>30 cells per μL</td>
    <td>97 cells per μL</td>
    <td>58 cells per μL</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th style="background-color:#233477">Time to Lymphocyte Recovery</th>
    <td>>6 months</td>
    <td>>1 year</td>
    <td>>9 months</td>
    <td>7-14 days</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th style="background-color:#233477">Disease Relapse</th>
    <td>17% at 66 mos (5.5 yrs)</td>
    <td>~70% within 10 months</td>
    <td>~ 50% under 3.5 years</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: The hover effect happens in the layer behind the table in the CodePen example too. What exactly is different between your table and the desired result (other than the colour)?

Comment: The codepen result appears right to me, when I hover my mouse to the table. https://imgur.com/T0ppsfv. That is the desired result, not the color, cos I know how to set it, but how to bring that hover color on top of my table layer.

Comment: Using your HTML above in this plunker, the hover is working as expected.  https://plnkr.co/edit/z3XzeWC0wWD5YBPcjHk7?p=preview. There must be another style over-riding your css on that page on your site.  I would say specifically the `z-index` property...

Answer (score 0):

```css
td:hover::before { 
    background-color: #eee;
    content: '';  
    height: 100%;
    left: -5000px;
    position: absolute;  
    top: 0;
    width: 10000px;   
    z-index: -2;        
}
```

You have missed to add  content: ' ';  for td:hover::before

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
* { 
  box-sizing:border-box;
  }
table {
  overflow: hidden; 
  display:inline-block;
  }
  td:hover{
    color: white;
  }
td:hover::before { 
  background: #233477; 
  content: ' '; 
  height: 100%; 
  left: -5000px; 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  width: 10000px; 
  z-index: -2;
  }
td:hover::after { 
  background: #a63f44; 
  content: ' '; 
  height: 10000px; 
  left: 0;
  position: absolute; 
  top: -5000px; 
  width: 100%; 
  z-index:-1;}
td, th {
  border: 1px solid #999; 
  padding: 10px; 
  position: relative;
  }
th {
  background-color:white;
  color:white;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
      <th style="background-color:#FFF"></th>
      <th style="background-color:#233477">HALT-MS Nash 2015 <b>BEAM</b></th>
      <th style="background-color:#233477">Crohns Haselblatt 2012 Brierley 2018 Cy-ATG</th>
      <th style="background-color:#233477">T1D Malmegrim 2017 Cy-ATG</th>
      <th style="background-color:#233477">AVM0703</th>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <th style="background-color:#233477">CD4 Nadir*</th>
    <td>22 cells per μL</td>
    <td>115 cell per μL</td>
    <td>155 cells per μL</td>
    <td><b>25 cells per μL</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th style="background-color:#233477">CD8 Nadir</th>
    <td>50 cells per μL</td>
    <td>172 cells per μL</td>
    <td>464 cells per μL</td>
    <td><b>1.4 cells per μL</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th style="background-color:#233477">B Lymphs Nadir</th>
    <td>12 cells per μL</td>
    <td>30 cells per μL</td>
    <td>97 cells per μL</td>
    <td>58 cells per μL</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th style="background-color:#233477">Time to Lymphocyte Recovery</th>
    <td>>6 months</td>
    <td>>1 year</td>
    <td>>9 months</td>
    <td>7-14 days</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th style="background-color:#233477">Disease Relapse</th>
    <td>17% at 66 mos (5.5 yrs)</td>
    <td>~70% within 10 months</td>
    <td>~ 50% under 3.5 years</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

changes in some css